# How to Format a string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have generated a string `"111,222,333"`. Using C# I would like to format it as follows:

```
MyId eq '111' or MyId eq '222' or Id eq '333'
```

Which method is a feasible solution to replace/modify the string for this?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-join-method-set-1/

Comment: Can you plz reopen qstn, i have edited the qstn to be clear

Comment: Voted (but we need 2 more votes)

Comment: Is that third one meant to be just `Id` or also `MyId`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this:

```
string generated = "111,222,333";
string[] parts = generated.Split(',');
IEnumerable<string> filters = parts.Select(x => $"MyId eq '{x}'"); 
string result = String.Join(" or ", filters);
```

That gives me `MyId eq '111' or MyId eq '222' or MyId eq '333'`.

Answer (score 0):

From your questions, it looks like you know exactly where you will put your value into a string. If it's the case, then you can do it with [string.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___) :

```
string data = "111,222,333";
string result = string.Format("MyId eq {0} or MyId eq {1} or Id eq {2}", data.Split(','));
```

**Dynamic way if your sentence is repeated**

```
string data = "111,222,333";
string[] pieces = data.Split(',');
List<string> sentences = new List<string>();
string sentence = "MyId eq {0}";

foreach (var piece in pieces)
{
   sentences.Add(string.Format(sentence, piece));
}

string result = string.Join(" or ", sentences);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0).Here is a demo:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var s = "111,222,333";
            var result = "MyId eq '" + s.Replace(",", "' or MyId eq '") + "'";
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

result:
[image]